# Using DevTools Autosave in visual studio

Tags: node.js, autosave, devtools

I learnt about DevTools Autosave, and was able to use it with sublime text. That was cool, but i wanted to be able to use if in visual studio also. I finally got it and want to share how i did it... Pretty easy though.

Answer (score 1):

Go to DevTools Autosave extenstion and click on option and just add the following references

```
    Match      ^http://localhost:11952/
    Save to    Documents/Visual Studio 2012/ProjectDirectory/
```

and map the little button to the server